# Chart.js not working after Django deployment on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, chart.js, momentjs

My Django site was working fine at `localhost:8000` but when I uploaded to Heroku, the charts no longer show up. Is there any typical reason why this would be? The errors I received in the console were `Uncaught Error: Chart.js - Moment.js could not be found! You must include it before Chart.js to use the time scale. Download at https://momentjs.com` and `The page at 'https://...com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Answer (score 1):

the error says it all. You try to load in the moment script over http but since this is an insecure protocol oit has been blocked, you have to load in the script over https.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js

Comment: I’m pretty new to websites and to chart.js, how can I do this?

Comment: It looks like you load in the library moment somewhere using a link, if you replace that link with the link from my answer it should work

Comment: I got the same error `The page at 'https:/../' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Can you share your code because it still tries to load it in over http

Comment: what part should i share? the tags that load these scripts?